# How to implement completion prefix suggestion per aliases in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, alias, completion

I cannot make complete suggester as described here:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3376

to work for aliases. Always get global index answers.

Can I filter suggestions for aliases in any way?

Comment: If possible, include the relevant part of the link in your question in order to make it self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know suggester is an experimental feature with quite a few limitations.
I followed this article http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams.

Comment: I have seen this solution too but thought that dedicated feature would be faster. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using that field definition in mapping:

```
"suggester": {                
   "type": "completion",     
   "context": {              
       "alias_name": {             
       "type": "category"
   }                     
}
```

And this is record structure:

```
record = {                                      
 'input': input_text,                      
 'output': output_text, 
 'context': {                                
     'alias_name': alias_name                        
 },                                          
 'weight': weight                            
}                
           `
```

.. but it seems like routing does not work (query hits all shards)